# create a database with existing sql code

Tags: database

How can I build a Database when i already have an existing SQL code?
I want a simple ".db" file.
Do you know any Programm that also run on Mac?

PS.: I am new with sql and Databases! ;)

froyo

Comment: .db is not a MySQL file format. Are you looking for SQLite?

Comment: what do you mean by ".db" file?

Comment: You are confused due to MSAcess and SQLite stuff. If you are talking about importing your database from .sql file Use something like phpmyadmin or heidisql to connect and then import the database and the data (if present) in file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most databases don't support putting all their data into a single file; MySQL, for example, creates one or two files per table in your database and one per index.

Also "building a database" doesn't make sense; a database is a container (like a file system) in which you can store information. If you want to save files to disk, you need to format the hard disk which creates the file system structure on it. If you want to store information in an SQL database, you need to set up the structure (which will create a lot of files in your file system but the database will know about that - you don't need to care about this).

I suggest to read the MySQL documentation to see how to [install](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installing.html) it and "format" part of your file system (= allocate space for your SQL tables) and the [tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tutorial.html) to see how to use MySQL.